# Android Studio Constraints not showing [Android Studio 3.1.3]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, constraints, android-constraintlayout

As shown in the image, the constraints are not visible besides activating them.
I have no idea how to solve this problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks.

[Edit]
Here is the XML Code, i haven't changed anything just added the Elements on the Design Tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_jump"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Jump Activity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_Name"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post the code and some more details in order for us to understand the problem so that we can help you with it. Please read this before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have error. Check what's the error and resolve them. To see errors click on the information icon `i` (red round icon near zoom controls)

Comment: This is the error:

Comment: Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

Comment: Show us your .xml code

Comment: Added the code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happen In Android Studio 3.1.3 when We are using appcompact-v7:28.0.0-alpha3 library (It automatically take this library). Open the build.gradle (Module:app) and check in the dependencies that which version of appcompact are you using. If "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3" then just changed the alpha3 to alpha1 or you can use the previous version 27 also. Now you can see it all component  in the blueprint.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a known **issue in appCompat library version** v7-28.0.0alpha/ which is being used directly with the latest build tools!

there are **two solutions** to this!

either **upgrade your build tools** from your sdk manager's tools tab!

or **second way**

is reverting back to 27.1.1

[image]

change the highlighted one into  as

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My version version of Android Studio (v3.1.4) has a slightly different line of code for appcompact with no mention of alpha3

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompact-v7:28.0.0-rc01'` so i just changed it to

above version 27 and clicked Sync Project With Gradle Files and it now shows the constraints perfectly.